# Rake db:seed before db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting error to `rake db:migrate` everytime I seed. I don't want to migrate because it fails due to looking up tables in my database that don't exist yet. How can I ignore this and continue with seed?

```
mmahalwy @ ~/Desktop/Code/API [56] → rake db:seed
You have 4 pending migrations:
  20141206123759 AddEsAnalyzerColumnToLanguageTable
  20141213090426 CreateTextFontView
  20141213090434 UpdateLemmaAndStem
  20141230124205 ChangeTextFontView
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

Note: I have a `structure.sql` file that has all the sql commands for creating the tables and seeding the data from yml. My migrations currently need to run AFTER the data/tables are in the database.

Comment: Sounds like you should fix migrations (or load from schema.rb) - not being to be able to run migrations is not a healthy state to be in.

Comment: Perhaps remove the pending migrations temporarily from your `db/migrations` folder?

Answer (score 6):

You could bypass rake altogether and 'seed' directly. I'm not really advocating it but it would solve your immediate problem:

```
rails runner ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_seed
```

You may want to look at the `db:structure:load` task to load your structure.sql file if that is all your seeding is doing.

Comment: Going to try this once I get home today!

Answer (score 4):

How can you save values to the tables that don't exist? The job of `rake db:migrate` is to create tables in the database.

`rake db:create` creates database

`rake db:migrate` creates tables in the database

`rake db:seed` creates records in the tables based on seed data

Comment: I have a structure.sql file that I want to seed into the database then do my migrations. Edited my question to reflect that

Comment: rake db:migrate also removes tables and columns. If you're using the seed feature to transfer information from old tables/columns to new ones prior to deleting them in a subsequent migration, then you will of course want to run the seed before running the migration.

Comment: I dont understand why running `rake db:setup` the first time does not pick up necessary migrations before seeding